# Difference in two angles in radians?

Tags: c#, wpf, math, trigonometry

I have a simple chart whereby the user can determine a start & end direction in radians. The control then draws the chart using an override of  `OnRender`. I am drawing the arcs with `StreamGeometryContext.ArcTo`. This method has an `IsLargeArc` property which determines how the arc is drawn (true for > 180 degrees (PI), false for < 180 degrees). I am determining this value from a condition which works fine:

```
 //Rule does not exceed 180 degrees in direction (radian), IsLargeArc= False else true
 if (Start < Math.PI && (End - Start) < Math.PI || //currently unknow condition in here to deal with < PI when start angle is > then end angle?)
  {
     //IsLargeArc = false;
  }
  else
  {
     //IsLargeArc= true;
  }
```

[image]

The issue comes when the start < end. e.g. From 270 degrees to 120 degrees. I need a condition to satisfy an angle over 180 degrees (PI) in this situation. Maths is not my strong point. I think I need to add PI*2 to the end and then somehow compare the two values but not sure on how to achieve this?

Comment: A full circle (ie 360 degrees) is equal to `2 * pi` radians, as you note.

Comment: "The issue comes when the start < end. e.g. From 270 degrees to 120 degrees. I need a condition to satisfy an angle over 180 degrees (PI) in this situation" - can you elaborate this more? What is expected?

Answer (score 4):

Well, you could add a full circle to the `end`, (or start; according to the direction) angle e.g.:

```
if (start < end)
    start += 2 * Math.PI; //full circle in radians.
```

This way you'll add a full circle to the end angle, which doesn't change the position for your drawing and results in a valid and correct angle if you subtract them (`start - end`).

Although I must say, I would expect a `start > end`condition.

If `start > end` or visa versa, than this tells you something about the direction.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Math.Abs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk4666yx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to get the absolute value of the difference.

Your code might look like the following:

```
  if  ((Start < Math.PI && Math.Abs(End - Start) < Math.PI) || 
        (Start > Math.PI && End - Start < 0 ))
    {
        //IsLargeArc = false;
    }
    else
    {
        //IsLargeArc= true;
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'start is < end and the resulting angle - PI...'

do you mean Start < End + Math.Abs(End - Start) - Math.PI

Comment: so in that case that you have described, do you want to handle it like a LargeArc or not?

Comment: then you don't  need another condition because Math.Abs(End - Start) < Math.PI is satisfying that condition

Answer (score 1):

```
  private bool IsLargeArc(Styled2DRange range)
    {
        double angleDiff = GetPositiveAngleDifference(End - Start);

        if (angleDiff > Math.PI)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private double GetPositiveAngleDifference(double angleDiff)
    {
        return (angleDiff + (2*Math.PI))%(2*Math.PI);
    }
```